# use span id value as a conditional javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this span in the html body:

```
<span id="username_status"></span>
```

snippet of sql query:

```
if($exist > 0)
    {
    echo 'Sorry, That username is Taken!'; //value in username_status
    }
    else{
    echo 'Username available!'; //value in username_status
    }
```

and i'm trying to use the query result to generate a form validation alert:

```
var s1 = document.getElementById('username_status').innerHTML;
 if (s1 === "Sorry, That username is Taken!")
  {
  alert("Please Change Your Username. It is already used.");
  return false;
  }
}
```

I've searched far and wide, but it looks i'm not getting anything. any help?

Comment: don't do that. it's easier to just embed a variable and check that. `var taken = <?php echo json_encode($exist > 0); ?>`, then `if (taken) { ... }`. as well, note that you're using innerHTML. there COULD be extra invisible tags and whatnot in the text you extract. try `.text()` instead of get ONLY text.

Comment: Why do you want to popup an alert when you have a message on the screen?

Comment: Marc B: it's an sql query, but i'll see what I can do. LiamB: it's actually part of a form validation. i already know if the username's taken or not, i just have to apply that to the form validation too. but maybe there's a better way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning a message you can return a status code like `status:success`.

And i think you should send an ajax request to handle this,if you want to use javascript:

Javascript(I assume you use jQuery):

```
$.post("your-php-file.php",{username:"some-username"},function(data){
   if(data.status == "success"){
        alert("This username is available");
   }
   else{
        alert("This username is already in use.");
   }
});
```

PHP:

```
if($exist > 0){
   $res['status'] = "success";
}
else{
   $res['status'] = "failed";
}
echo json_encode($res);
```

Comment: actually, the exist part is an sql query.